# How do I send image canvas data to Transloadit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, canvas, transloadit

[Transloadit](https://transloadit.com/docs/) appears to have only a Upload Form API. I wish to send the contents of my canvas to Transloadit like so:

```
data = canvas.toDataURL();

// POST this data to Transloadit
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api2.transloadit.com/assemblies',
    // what goes here?
}).done(function() {
    console.log('Done uploading!');
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: It is possible, since that API expect data encoded as `multipart/form-data`. Now a normal HTML form with that set as `encoding` attribute value would do that automatically; since your image data does not originate from a file upload input however you would have to “built” that format yourself. How to do that is a little to broad to answer here, so please do your own research on that.

Comment: I think you might find this xhr solution interesting https://github.com/tim-kos/transloadit_xhr/blob/master/transloadit_xhr.js#L70

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Transloadit still does not support base64 data, but with newer browsers it's possible to take base64 data from a variable, convert it to binary, and send it in a file upload.

http://support.transloadit.com/discussions/questions/8587-how-to-upload-a-canvas-image-to-transloadit